# Selecting data from two joined tables

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 tables: 
`Users` and `Cars`. The tables are joined in third table: `Users_Cars_Join`.

Is there any fast (direct) method to select data from both tables (`Cars`, `Users`) without using `'inner join'` statement to join `Users` with `Users_Cars_Join` and than using this one more time to join `Users_Cars_join` to `Cars`?

I wonder how it should be done correctly and profesionally.

Cars:

- Id
- Name

Users:

- Id
- Name

Users_Cars_Join:

- Id
- UserId
- CarId

Comment: I get that table structure and i cant change it.

Comment: What is the connection between Cars & Users??

Comment: If you cannot change the table structure I guess you will always have to use joins on the Users_car_join table. There is no other element that clarifies a link between users and cars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to bypass the linktable but if you dread writing the joins all the time, you can create a view that does just that

```
CREATE VIEW UsersCars AS 
SELECT  c.ID AS CarID
        , c.Name AS CarName
        , u.ID AS UserID
        , u.Name AS UserName
FROM    Cars c
        INNER JOIN Users_Cars_Join ucj ON ucj.CarID = c.ID
        INNER JOIN Users u ON u.ID = ucj.UserID
```

Using the view would be as simple as

```
SELECT * FROM UsersCars
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbdea/1) for a demo

Comment: @Ellbar - A view in essence is nothing more than a shortcut to prevent you from writing a complete statement. When using a view in a select, the engine actually replaces the name with the complete underlying statement. Don't get to overzeallus on using views though. It's not difficult to make a mess of things when you do *(read as, it can simplify things when used judiciously but when everything becomes a view, you will lose the overview and performance problems might creep in)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the old stye for joining tables like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, u.id, u.name, ...
  FROM cars c, users u, user_cars_join uc
 WHERE u.id = uc.userid
   AND c.id = uc.carid
```

Things to note:

1. The `user_cars_join` table exists because it denotes the many-to-many relationship between users and their cars. If you remove this table from the structure then the `users` and `cars` tables are not related anymore.
2. You need to understand the phenomena of one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

   - A one-to-one relationship is where one entity in one set relates to only one entity in the other set. In your case it would have been one user owning only one single car which is not practical. A single person can own multiple cars.
   - A one-to-many relationship is where one entity in one set relates to multiple entities in the other set, and, one entity in the other set relates to only one entity in the first set. In your case it would have been one user owns multiple cars but a single car is owned by a single user. You can have this sort of relationship, especially when the car has a registration number. The schema would look something like this:

     ```
     User (userid, name)
     car_sales (carid, userid, registration_number)
     Car (carid, name, brand, model)
     ```

     Note that the `userid` in the `car_sales` table denotes which user owns this car. Also, the `carid` in `car_sales` table refers to the unique `carid` in `car` table.

     Also note that in this model, one user can own multiple cars. One model of car can have multiple instances (items of it) sold to multiple users.

     This is the most widely used and acceptable model for representing these relationships.
   - A many-to-many relationship, as implemented in your example, is when multiple entities in one set are related to multiple entities in the other set and vice versa. There has to be a separate relationships table to denote the relationships between the entities, which in your case is the `user_car_join` table.